# Wrong count of values when using SUM and IF in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, if-statement, count, sum

I'm having a count problem in my database query when using the IF function in combination with sum.

Example database with same behavior :

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `system` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Example data :

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `system`, `status`, `timestamp`) VALUES
(3, 'systema', 'ok', '2017-03-25 06:43:03'),
(4, 'systema', 'ok', '2017-03-25 06:43:09'),
(5, 'systema', 'fail', '2017-03-25 06:43:16'),
(6, 'systema', 'ok', '2017-03-25 06:43:22'),
(7, 'systema', 'ok', '2017-03-25 06:43:31'),
(8, 'systema', 'fail', '2017-03-25 07:12:28'),
(9, 'systema', 'fail', '2017-03-25 07:13:07'),
(10, 'systema', 'ok', '2017-03-25 07:13:13'),
(11, 'systema', 'ok', '2017-03-25 07:26:21'),
(12, 'systema', 'fail', '2017-03-25 07:26:41'),
(13, 'systema', 'fail', '2017-03-25 07:28:52'),
(14, 'systema', 'fail', '2017-03-25 07:29:13'),
(15, 'systema', 'fail', '2017-03-25 07:29:39');
```

Make sure all vars are empty :

```
mysql> set @prev_system:=null;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @prev_status:=null;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @prev_time:=null;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Now we do the databasequery without count:

```
mysql> select @prev_system as old_system, @prev_status as old_status, @prev_time 
as old_time, if (@prev_status <> status and @prev_system = system and @prev_time 
< timestamp,1,NULL) as hops, @prev_system:=system as system, @prev_status:=status as 
status, @prev_time:=timestamp as timestamp from test;
```

The result:

```
+------------+------------+---------------------+------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| old_system | old_status | old_time            | hops | system  | status | timestamp           |
+------------+------------+---------------------+------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| systema    | fail       | 2017-03-25 08:29:39 | NULL | systema | ok     | 2017-03-25 07:43:03 |
| systema    | ok         | 2017-03-25 07:43:03 | NULL | systema | ok     | 2017-03-25 07:43:09 |
| systema    | ok         | 2017-03-25 07:43:09 |    1 | systema | fail   | 2017-03-25 07:43:16 |
| systema    | fail       | 2017-03-25 07:43:16 |    1 | systema | ok     | 2017-03-25 07:43:22 |
| systema    | ok         | 2017-03-25 07:43:22 | NULL | systema | ok     | 2017-03-25 07:43:31 |
| systema    | ok         | 2017-03-25 07:43:31 |    1 | systema | fail   | 2017-03-25 08:12:28 |
| systema    | fail       | 2017-03-25 08:12:28 | NULL | systema | fail   | 2017-03-25 08:13:07 |
| systema    | fail       | 2017-03-25 08:13:07 |    1 | systema | ok     | 2017-03-25 08:13:13 |
| systema    | ok         | 2017-03-25 08:13:13 | NULL | systema | ok     | 2017-03-25 08:26:21 |
| systema    | ok         | 2017-03-25 08:26:21 |    1 | systema | fail   | 2017-03-25 08:26:41 |
| systema    | fail       | 2017-03-25 08:26:41 | NULL | systema | fail   | 2017-03-25 08:28:52 |
| systema    | fail       | 2017-03-25 08:28:52 | NULL | systema | fail   | 2017-03-25 08:29:13 |
| systema    | fail       | 2017-03-25 08:29:13 | NULL | systema | fail   | 2017-03-25 08:29:39 |
+------------+------------+---------------------+------+---------+--------+---------------------+
```

In column 'hops' should be a '1' when status has been changed compared with old status, and 'NULL' if no change occurred, so far so good.

But when i add SUM statement to the IF statement, i do not get the expected '5' as exprected result in hops column:

Query :

```
mysql> select @prev_system as old_system, @prev_status as old_status, @prev_time 
as old_time, sum(if (@prev_status <> status and @prev_system = system and @prev_time < timestamp,1,NULL)) as hops, @prev_system:=system as system, 
@prev_status:=status as status, @prev_time:=timestamp as timestamp from test;
```

Result :

```
+------------+------------+----------+------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| old_system | old_status | old_time | hops | system  | status | timestamp           |
+------------+------------+----------+------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| NULL       | NULL       | NULL     |    7 | systema | ok     | 2017-03-25 07:43:03 |
+------------+------------+----------+------+---------+--------+---------------------+
```

I think i miss a very small thing here, who can help me out getting the sum right ?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not ordering them in any way, they may appear in any order and that may affect things

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that, but it makes no difference to the result, i added order by system, timestamp to the end of the query, result and output is same, and result is still '7', as you can see in the previous output, the dataorder seems ok, but the result is unexpected

Comment: Yes, in the latter order doesn't matter because there is only one row. You may need a sub query

Comment: I'm trying to prevent subquery's since the real dataset is very large and growing, and subquery's are slow, I hope anyone can help me with a solution, since i'm not that experienced in this kind of enhanced mysql. Thanks Sami.